# how to recover a destroyed asp file（.inc）?

Tags: asp-classic

the asp file is unreadable because of unkown reason, but it still can work normally. now i want to change the function, so i have to recover the messy code and edit it. is there anyone know how to recover the destroyed asp file? thanks!

Comment: It is not corrupted, but [encoded (possibly) using the MS Script Encoder](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20011123.asp). the link to the decoder in that link currently does not work, you will have to look around for it.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ thank you so much! i have found the Windows Script Decoder, and it works perfectly! i'll give the download link if anyone'll need it.[link](http://ms.x6x8.com/attachment/scrdec18.rar)

Comment: i was able de-encode only one function from this script. function which are setup connection with database (contain your SA password)

Comment: @Zam i tryed another script wihch i need to edit, and it does work. i think maybe the reason why it doesn't work on this script is the codepage.maybe i need to find another decoder which can decode utf-8 scripts.

Comment: @vivianey can you provide link to solution you found?

Comment: @Zam i transfered the codepage from utf-8 to gb2312 and the windows script decoder can decode every English words, it just doesn't work for the Chinese annotation. it still has some problem, i'll publish the solution if i find it..